# How to convert the scientific notation to required decimal in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame column I read from excel file. After reading the excel, I see that one of my column is denoted in scientific notation. As shown below. But I would like to get it in decimal.

Given:

```
Volume
7.646507e+02    
8.076734e+02
8.076734e+02
```

Expected:

```
Volume

764.6506541
807.6734405
807.6734405
```

Not sure if the problem is with reading the excel file. Because i do not see the scientific notation in excel file.

```
df = pd.read_excel('btc.xlsx',index_col=None )
```

Tried:

```
df['Volume'].map(int)
```

What i get is int values like

```
Volume
764
807
807
```

But is there any option i can get decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.7f}'.format